# Populate data in a data frame

Tags: r

creating data of 10000 questions, I need to do each candidate_id has 100 q's to answer how do I populate this data of 1 candidate each with 100 questions?

```
df <- data.frame(candidate_id=sample(1:100,10000,T),
                 question_id=sample(1:10000,100,T),
                 selected_answer=sample(1:4,100,T))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#make data frame
df <- data.frame(candidate_id = 1:100,
                 question_id = sample(1:10000, 10000, TRUE),
                 selected_answer = sample(1:4, 10000, TRUE))
#test
unique(table(df$candidate_id))
# [1] 100
```